# Emulate Browser Request by phpQuery - URL Rewrite modified the path

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, phpquery

I am using [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to simulate a browser request. Codes are simple as follow:

```
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
phpQuery::browserGet($url, 'success1');
function success1($browser) {
    print $browser;
}
```

where URL is `http://www.etk.cc/bmw/EN/parts/info/13547556118`.

However, I received an Exception of:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Uri_Exception' with message
>   'Path "/bmw/EN/parts/info/http://www.etk.cc/bmw/EN/parts/info/Throttle
>   housing Assy/13547556118/" is not a valid HTTP path'

It is believed that URL Rewrite changed the URL to `http://www.etk.cc/bmw/EN/parts/info/Throttle housing Assy/13547556118/` but the phpQuery or Zend library does not recognize the URL Rewrite.

How do I resolve this issue (loading the correct URL)?

*Note: I can't use the URL after URL Rewrite, as the URL contains the product name & has no pattern.*

Comment: It's probably a bug in the phpQuery or browser plugin - you might want to check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481677/phpquery-webbrowser-plugin-using-cookies

Comment: How about just using the redirect url and replace the space with a `%20`?

Comment: @pguardiario the redirect url is dynamically fetched from their DB and reflect as a rewritten URL.

Comment: In that case maybe there's a way to turn off auto-follow and replace the space in the location header.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

I first use the following codes to obtain the **header** of the request:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
$out = curl_exec($ch);
```

From the `Location:` header, I can know the rewritten URL. Then, I use the `phpQuery` again to obtain the required information using the newly obtained rewritten URL.

*Footnote: I do think the Exception in the question is a bug in phpQuery.*

Comment: That's good but it probably makes sense to let curl get the whole response. Then you can load that into the (non-buggy) html parser of your choice.

Comment: I wish I could use cURL to get whole response, but the reason of using `phpQuery` or `Snoopy` (another HTML parser) is that I have to obtain some AJAX loaded contents within the page after the page is loaded. cURL call cannot obtain such information (replay the AJAX call is not an option, as the script checks for request origin)

Comment: Curl can certainly make any request that phpQuery can make, I don't know why you would think it couldn't.

Comment: Really? Including delayed-loaded contents via Javascript? I don't think so.

Comment: phpQuery doesn't have a javascript engine, unless I'm misunderstanding your meaning you're giving it too much credit.

Comment: `phpQuery::browserGet()` simulates a web browser & fetch all contents AFTER Javascript in the page is loaded. I tried it & works fine.